# how to build lucene index with spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, lucene

I want a code demo or some ideas to build lucene index with spark cluster. 
I have tried some ways. But I still don't know how to use the lucene's IndexWriter in spark.
My input data is like this in lines:sellerId, productId, title

I want the output is lucene's index files.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [spark-lucenerdd](https://github.com/zouzias/spark-lucenerdd). For a quick introduction on the library take a look at [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/zouzias/lucenerdd-for-geospatial-search-and-entity-linkage).

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually done the following and it works great:

```
public class LuceneDatasetIndexService implements DatasetIndexService, Serializable
{

    private static final String SCHEMA_JSON = "schema.json";

    @Autowired
    private transient FileUtility fileUtility;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void indexDataset(Dataset<Row> dataset, Path indexStorePath) throws IOException
    {
        if (!fileUtility.exists(indexStorePath))
        {
            Files.createDirectories(indexStorePath);
            Path schemaPath = indexStorePath.resolve(SCHEMA_JSON);
            String prettyJson = dataset.schema().prettyJson();
            Files.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(prettyJson.getBytes()), schemaPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        //Path is not serializable
        String path = indexStorePath.toString();
        dataset.foreachPartition(new ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>()
        {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void call(Iterator<Row> t) throws Exception
            {
                Path indexPath = Paths.get(path);
                StructType schema = SparkSchemaUtil.readSparkSchemaFromFile(indexPath.resolve(SCHEMA_JSON));
                RowIndexWriter writer = null;
                while (writer == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer = new LuceneRowIndexWriter(schema, indexPath);
                    } catch (LockObtainFailedException e)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                }

                try {
                    while (t.hasNext())
                    {
                        writer.indexRow(t.next());
                    }
                }
                finally 
                {
                    writer.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public List<Row> find(Path indexStorePath, Collection<Filter> filters, int size) throws IOException
    {
        Path schemaPath = indexStorePath.resolve(SCHEMA_JSON);

        StructType schema = SparkSchemaUtil.readSparkSchemaFromFile(schemaPath);

        RowIndexSearcher searcher = new LuceneRowIndexSearcher(schema, indexStorePath);
        return searcher.search(filters, indexStorePath, size);
    }
```

This way there is no transfer of data between nodes for indexing, and every partition is written to the lucene index one at a time (you can't open multiple indexers at the same time)